# How to create a Global Timeout Background Worker in PHP, Flash, or ASP.NET

Tags: php, asp.net, flash

**Background**:

I have an inherited web application that uses Flash AS2 and PHP 5.x on IIS (Windows 2008 R2) with MySQL. There is a setting for a timeout that does not work - no code was ever written but the client has the radio button to turn it on and off. The setting is saved in the MySQL database.

**Requirement**:

The timeout should give a pop-up when there is 1 minute to go and then redirect to a new page after the time has expired.

**Question**:

Is there a way to use a global timer as a standalone application (like a background worker in DotNet) without effecting the existing Flash or PHP code? I can think of several ways to include code in the application but I was needing a way to do it without having to add code to the 400 or so pages of existing code.

The solution can use ASP.NET or PHP as both are available on the Server.

Comment: I know this may be impossible but I just wanted to double check before declaring it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX cam trigger a JavaScript Timer event for the duration set in the database.

Thus when the timeout is about to expire an Alert Box can be shown to the user and once the timeout expires the page can redirect to another one.

This would just change the code on a single HTML page and not the Flash and PHP code.

The user session is handled within Flash (poorly) and thus would require a logon if the user selected back.